# NodeJs/MongoDB - How to update a 200kb Collection every few seconds and keep it anyhow still readable between?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to update a ~200kb collection every few seconds (actually replace all the data inside it with new data just fetched from an API provider). The question is, is the collection used in a project with Node.js/Express with database managed by mongodb/mongoose, still readable and can be safety consumed in my API endpoint? Is the collection just locked in a cache till all data is 100% updated? (atomic process) or is there a risk to get sometime only inconsistent or partial data?